# AT Command — forwarding call

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, ussd

I try to forward an incomming call via this AT-Command:

```
AT+CCFC=1,1,"+4930xxxxxxxx",145;
```

But it isn't working (on the M10 Quectel GSM Shield from Arduino).

My second approach is doing this with an USSD-Line wrapped in a AT-Command like this:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"**21*+4930xxxxxxxx#",15
```

but I also receive an error. Anyone know what's wrong?

UPDATE:
I found out that there its necessary to choose mode "3" at the 2nd position. That means that the following telephonenumber is going to be registred. Like so:

```
AT+CCFC=1,3,"+4930xxxxxxxx",145,1,1
```

Unfortunately I can't save the current incomming number, before doing the forwarding process. After setting up the callforward-AT-Command the call goes directly to the forwarded number. So it seems that I have no access to the new telephone number. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Your posted code is showing stylized quotes “ “ but I suspect you want regular ones " ".  Are you using regular quotes in your original code?

Comment: Oh you are right, but there is no change after replacing the quotes. I guess the serial monitor just see it as regular " quote — edit: changed the quotes above to avoid any misreading

Comment: Are you sure your specific device supports call forwarding?

Comment: regarding to this manual it should support this: http://www.quectel.com/UploadFile/Product/Quectel_M10_AT_Commands_Manual_V4.0.pdf — on page 44 there is the AT-Command for forwarding. By commanding: "AT+CCFC=?" there is also feedback.

Answer (score -1):

LOOK TRY TO OPEN SIM CODE PIN 
FOR ME CODE PIN IS 0000

AT+CPIN=0000
AFTER
AT+CCFC=1,3,"+4930xxxxxxxx",145,1,1